# preg_match: alphanumeric only, begin with letter, end with digit

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

What should a preg_match statement look like that will validate that a string to 1) contain only alphanumeric characters, 2) begin with at least 2 letters, and 3) end with at least 2 digits?

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('/^[a-z]{2}[[:alnum:]]*\d{2}$/iD', $subject);
```

Comment: +1, for the use of the D modifier.

Comment: Thanks, it works great!  The only non alphanumeric character I can find it allows is an underscore - any way to keep that out as well?

Comment: With the new modification, valid input is showing up as invalid.  That's ok, I'll just allow underscores and get rid of them after the validation.  Thanks for your help!